# Type safety in C# using custom ValueType

Tags: c#

In my code I have variables of type **System.Double that either represent a quantity or a quantityDifference**. In order to make my code safer, I would like to pass in a value of either **type Quantity or QuantityDelta rather than double** (to avoid passing in the the wrong value).

I can create a struct or class with a Value property or field but then I have to allocate memory for it and use the .Value syntax to use it:

```
public class Quantity
{
   public Quantity(double value) { Value = value; }
   public double Value;
}
```

and

```
var difference = new Quantity(differenceValue);
var used = difference.Value;
```

Is there a way to create a custom value type for this purpose, so the code reads like

```
Quantity difference = differenceValue;
var used = difference
```

Comment: I think you want to look further in to [Operator overloading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading)

Comment: I might be missunderstanding the question, but why don't you just make `Value` a property?

Comment: Field or property, I will have to reference it explicitly in my code. This is just about syntactic sugar.

Comment: I think instead of using classes you should be using structs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [implicit operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators).

```
public struct Quantity
{
    private readonly double value;

    public Quantity(double value) { this.value = value; }
    public double Value => value;

    public static implicit operator double(Quantity value) => value.value;
    public static implicit operator Quantity(double value) => new Quantity(value);
}
```

Also, since you are simply wrapping a value type, it would be best to use a `struct` rather than a `class`.

Comment: This is what I was referring to with my comment. You probably want to use a struct

Comment: @mathis1337 - I did use a struct.

Comment: I know. I was talking to OP, and referring to comment i made above. I Am saying you have correct answer imo.

Comment: @mathis1337 - Fair enough. I will point it out in my answer.

Comment: No need to point anything out. My comment was to help OP. You have good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Operator overloading will help with `Quantity difference = differenceValue;`, specifically an implicit conversion operator for converting a *double* value into a Quantity struct instance.

However, nothing will help you with convincing the compiler to choose the *double* type for the var-declared *used* variable in `var used = difference`. Because `var` instructs the compiler to use the type of the right-hand expression as the type for the var-declared variable *used*. Which is *Quantity* here. I.e., the compiler will understand `var used = difference` as `Quantity used = difference`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick sample I created for a `Quantity` struct that has basic operations of Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication, and Division.

```
public readonly struct Quantity
{
    private readonly double num;

    public Quantity(double number)
    {
        num = number;
    }

    public static Quantity operator +(Quantity a, Quantity b) => new Quantity(a.num + b.num);
    public static Quantity operator -(Quantity a, Quantity b) => new Quantity(a.num - b.num);
    public static Quantity operator *(Quantity a, Quantity b) => new Quantity(a.num * b.num);
    public static Quantity operator /(Quantity a, Quantity b)
    {
        if (b.num == 0)
        {
            throw new DivideByZeroException();
        }

        return new Quantity(a.num / b.num);
    }

    public override string ToString() => $"{num}";
}
```

A few quick test cases

```
var a = new Quantity(5);
var b = new Quantity(2);
Debug.WriteLine(a + b);  // output: 7
Debug.WriteLine(a - b);  // output: 3
Debug.WriteLine(a * b);  // output: 10
Debug.WriteLine(a / b);  // output: 2.5
```

If you do want the difference returned in a type called `QuantityDelta` you could replace the `-` operator above with:

> public static QuantityDelta operator -(Quantity a, Quantity b) => new QuantityDelta(a.num - b.num);

And, add a new `QuantityDelta` struct as per:

```
public readonly struct QuantityDelta
{
    private readonly double num;

    public QuantityDelta(double number)
    {
        num = number;
    }

    public override string ToString() => $"{num}";
}
```

Comment: Seems like the OP would actually want the minus operator to return a `QuantityDelta`